# Using a query that is stored in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2008-r2, nested

My database has two tables: `t_computers` and `t_queries`.

This query shows me which computers are laptops

```
select *
from t_computers
where type = 'Laptop'
```

In the table `t_queries` I have stored dynamic SQL queries.

```
SELECT QuerySQL
from t_query
where QueryName = 'Clients that have not been started in 30 days'
```

The first result is the SQL query that would give me this information.

Now for the complicated part, I want to only select computers that have the type 'Laptop' and are returned if I run the query that is stored in the table.

So something like this

```
select *
from t_computers
where type = 'Laptop' and
      (computer is returned for (SELECT QuerySQL 
                                 from query 
                                 where QueryName = 'Clients that have not been started in 30 days'))
```

Is this even possible? I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

I have used a very simplified example. 
Some background information on why I want to use the query saved in the table: With our Client Management System (similar to SCCM) Administrators can easily create "views" of Clients. For example Filtering out all Computers that have an IP starting with 10.*. As soon as they save the view, a SQL query is created and saved in the table t_queries. This one query that I want to compare against changes quite often.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: executing sql stored in the db doesn't sound like a good idea to me at all

Comment: using MS SQL @Barranka

Comment: In my opinion this is the only solution that is maintenance free @ControlAltDel

Comment: `In my opinion this is the only solution that is maintenance free` - Thus spake the master programmer: "Though a program be but three lines long, someday it will have to be maintained." -- [The Tao of Programming](http://www.canonical.org/~kragen/tao-of-programming.html)

Comment: Why not create a view instead storing sql in a table that you have use dynamic sql to run? Would make this type of thing a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, but as said by the commenters, I strongly unadvise you to execute arbitrary code coming from your users, no matter how much you trust them. You would have very little possibilities to enforce security rules and may open yourself to devastating security breaches.

The way it is properly done in other systems is to use a specific query language (custom or not) that you interpret and *"translate"* to SQL if needed. That allows you to limit the possible operations to what is strictly necessary.

After that disclaimer, here is an answer to your question (untested, I don't have SQL Server on this laptop so I may have messed up a bit with the quotes) :

```
exec('select *
from t_computers
where type = ''Laptop'' and
      (computer is returned for ('+SELECT TOP(1) QuerySQL 
                                 from query 
                                 where QueryName = 'Clients that have not been started in 30 days'+'))');
```